# Apps for Office JS API: How to bind anything other than RichText Content Control

Tags: javascript, office-addins, apps-for-office, office-js

What is the correct way to bind anything other than RichText Content Control in Word 2013 using Office javascript API?

As far as I can see it is non-existent.

In many documents it is told about TableBinding being usable in Word as well, but I couldn't find an example that works on Word.

What I would like to do is to put a table in a specific point of Word document.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done as of now (Office API v1.1)

Hopefully in future releases MS will add more CC types. For now, best bet is to create and use html coercion type as Richtext Content Control, or OOXML coercion type.